# Проблема с циклом while

Tags: php, сессия, php7, while

Привет. Есть такая проблема. Не удовлетворяется условие цикла.

```
    function checkclose()
{
  global $_SESSION;
  if ($_SESSION["closesession"])
  {
      unset($_SESSION["closesession"]);
      exit();
  }

}

$seconds = 30;

while((!$close) or ($seconds == 0))
{
  session_start();
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM order WHERE message_id = '$message_id'");
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
  $status_read = $row['status_read'];
  if($status_read == 'yes') {
    $close = true;
  }
  $seconds = $seconds - 5;
  checkclose();
  session_write_close();
  sleep(5);
}

session_start();
$_SESSION["closesession"] = true;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Я думаю сам цикл while не крутиться а вместо этого каждый раз заново крутиться весь код. Там внутри цикла есть обращение к функции checkclose(); вот и оно заново запускает все сначала и поэтому переменная $seconds всегда имеет значение равная к 30.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
while((!$close) or ($seconds == 0))
```

используйте

```
while((!$close) and ($seconds != 0))
```

чтобы цикл продолжался пока ни одно условие (`$close == true`, `$seconds == 0`) не выполнилось.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Не стоит. C удовольствием  :-)